# Freezing water in a bottle

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, water

Why is it when you freeze water you are not able to get same amount(volume) of water back when ice is melted back to liquid water.

Comment: Says who?  References?  Did you do the experiment?  How'd it go?  How did you define the amount of water?

Comment: Are you speaking about mass of the water or volume of the water?

Answer (score 3):

When water freezes it expands. If you are freezing water in a sealed plastic bottle, this may stretch the plastic making it appear that the level has lowered when it returns to a liquid state in a slightly stretched bottle. However in a sealed container, where there is no loss from evaporation or sublimation, the amount (mass) of water does not change.

Answer (score 2):

When water freezes its volume increases. This is one of the peculiarities of water. So when the ice changes back into water, its volume decreases back to what it was before it was frozen. In any case, the mass of the water does not change.

Hope this helps.